# How can I make a stub using Mockito to simulate the operation of a transaction in a reactive stack

Tags: java, spring, mockito, reactive-streams

How can I make a stub using Mockito to simulate the operation of a transaction in a reactive stack

- example code

```java
.as(customerMono -> txOperator.transactional(customerMono))
```

```java
    private Mono<User> findUserByPhone(String mobilePhone) {
        return service.findByMobilePhone(mobilePhone)
                .flatMap(customer -> {
                    System.out.println(customer);
                    return Mono.just(customer);
                })
                .singleOrEmpty()
                .as(customerMono -> txOperator.transactional(customerMono))
                .flatMap(customer -> {
                    System.out.println(customer);
                   return Mono.just(customer);
                })

.....
```

I tried this,

```java
    protected void mockWhenTxOperatorTransactional(){
        Mockito.when(
                this.txOperator.transactional(buildUserAsMono())
        ).thenReturn(buildUserAsMono());
    }

    private Mono<User> buildUserAsMono(){

        int accountEnabled = 1;

        User user = User.builder()
                .enabled(accountEnabled)
                .mobilePhone(this.phoneNumberExpected)
                .build();

        return Mono.just(user);
    }
```

however I get the error anyway.

> Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.service.UserService.findCustomerByPhone(

Who knows, tell me an example, please

Answer (score 0):

```java
    protected void mockWhenUsingTransactionalOperator(){
        Mockito.when(
                        this.transactionalOperator.transactional(
                                any(Mono.class)
                        )
                )
                .thenReturn(
                        buildUserAsMono()
                );
    }
```

buildUserAsMono() - here is the object that is obtained at the output, after calling **this.transactionalOperator.transactional(....)**